# Cannot close Internet Explorer with Powershell after form submission

Tags: powershell

I open a page, fill in fields, click submit. The submit does do a redirect. When I try $ie2.quit() it won't close the window. Any ideas?

```
$ie2 = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie2.visible=$true
$ie2.navigate("http://localhost/useradd.jsp")
start-sleep -seconds 3

$ie2.Document.getElementById("UserId").value = "test1"
$ie2.Document.getElementById("UserName").value = "test1 user"
$ie2.Document.getElementById("UserPassword").value = "12345$"

$submitButton = $ie2.document.getElementsByTagName("input") 
Foreach($element in $submitButton )
{
    #look for this field by value this is the field(look for screenshot below) 
    if($element.value -eq "Add"){
    Write-Host $element.click()
}
$ie2.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add something like `while ($ie2.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }` before the `$ie2.quit()` Statement to make sure, the COM Object is repsonsive.